# Link html form inputs to javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am still new to all this so I'm probably not using all the correct terminology. I was wondering if it is possible to link javascript objects to html inputs. For instance, I am using http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/. When I click on a event in the calendar a callback triggers and I'm passed the event object which contains the title, start, end, etc.

In angular one can link an input to an object by means of

```
<input type="text" name="title" ng-model="event.title">
```

So if I click on an event it sets the global object "event" to a different object then the value of the "title" input would change to the title of the event that I clicked on. The same with all the other input fields, so I do not manually have to go and change every input with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    function clickEvent(event)
    {
         $.('#title').val(event.title);
         ....
    }
</script>
```

Is this possible in normal javascript/jQuery, and if so where can I get some proper documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.on("input", function(){ ... })` event, to get the value of the input and store it in a object, when the value changes.

```
obj = {};

$("input[name=title]").on("input", function(){  //jquery on input fires every time the input value is changed
    obj["title"] = $(this).val(); // set the obj's title property to the value of the input
});
```

[Here is a fiddle for it!](http://jsfiddle.net/wCVhg/)

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I was looking for. I would still have to do it to every field, then I might as well just change every field manually like in my original post. I was hoping for a more elegant solution where I can just link every input field to an attribute of an object like `<input type="title" name="title" id="title" bind="window.event">` and simply set window.event = { event object returned } when one clicks on an event.